# How can I untangle a very fine jewellery chain?

Tags: jewelry

I have a necklace with a very fine chain that has got a knot in it. I'm finding it near impossible to manipulate the knot effectively. Is there some trick or life hack I can use?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try applying baby oil or baby power to make it more slippery.

Or you can try to put a pin in the middle of the knot to jiggle it more loose to start with

Good luck!

Comment: The pin trick worked. I used safety pins to stop the loops from closing again once I'd teased them open.

Comment: I've used toothpicks.

Answer (score 4):

Baby powder  or corn starch can be sprinkled on the knot and worked into the knot. Either one absorbs the body oils that contribute to the tendency to form knots. Then, use pins to tease the chain apart.
Source: Personal experience working with jewelry at Thrift Store.

Answer (score 2):

I found that a large amount of dish soap to help the knot slip and slide and two sets of tweezers to allow one to grip individual links of delicate chains works well. Also a magnifying light that allows you to see exactly which links of the chain are connected to which can be really helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've used a knife with a sharp point to help 'pick' away at a knotted necklace of my wife's. It admittedly took a few evenings but I've untangled chains that normally she would just have thrown away.

Answer (score 1):

hmm I am thinking of putting the necklace in a bowl of hot water (if it doesn't damage the necklace), since it makes the knock to expand and it makes a bit loose then you can use a needle to further loosen the knock and eventually open it with your hands.

Answer (score 1):

Pro tip: use your phone’s camera to magnify the knot. With two push pins and a LOT of patience, you can get out the worst knots, without applying chemicals or powders that might tarnish the metal.

Answer (score 0):

I find a needle works really well. I stick pointed end right into knot, gently work needle in a circle, as it gets loose enough to pull away so room to grasp between finger tips from that point it will continue to loosen so repeat the steps.

Comment: This is very similar to the accepted answer.